# Using Google/G-Suite as a user backend for django?

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-apps, google-workspace

I'm looking at building a django app specifically designed for G-Suite domains. It requires users to be logged in to G-Suite, and would get permissions from groups in G-Suite. I know I could achieve this using django-allauth or similar, but that would involve the django app duplicating the user information in it's own database. In the interests of preventing unnecessary replication, is it feasible to have django directly use Google APIs to handle user logins, but still program the rest of the app in a django kind of a way? Are there any libraries that implement this? If not in django, are there other (python) frameworks that can do this?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I used Django Social Auth.  You are correct that the user info is duplicated.  I also use the Google APIs to connect to GSuite via service account tokens so no user login required.  The service account has domain delegation so it can read all emails etc.  But by far and away the better solution for us was to use Google Identity Aware Proxy if you are on Gsuite and you are prepared to pay for IAP + a GCE instance (which was easier for us than running Django on GAE)